# How to create an XSD that references another XSD that exists in a separate jar - dependency

Tags: java, xsd

I want to create an XSD, lets call that XSD_A, that resides under module: module_A.
I want to reference, by either including or importing another XSD, lets call that XSD_B from another module, module_B.

XSD_B resides under the resources of module_B and should therefore be packaged into a JAR.
I want the XSD_A to be compiled by xjc to create Java Classes on compile time, which I am properly using as a maven configuration without a problem so far.

XSD_B is an official XSD that starts with:

```
  <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://my.own.url" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" targetNamespace="http://my.own.targetNamespace" elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" vc:minVersion="1.1">
```

My initial approaches are:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns="http://example.com/b"
xmlns:ec="http://my.own.targetNamespace"
targetNamespace="http://example.com/b"
elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:import namespace="http://my.own.targetNamespace" schemaLocation="/PATH_TO_REFENCE_XSD_B"/>
```

I have also tried to use:

```
 schemaLocation="/PATH_TO_REFENCE_XSD_B"/
```

Without success.
My questions are:

1. How can I do this?
2. Will the XSD be build properly in non-local compilation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and most reliable way is to extract the dependent schema out of the JAR file and put aside your own schema.

Comment: Currently I am doing something like that. I am unpacking the jar with maven, and then I am copying the target XSDs in my resources folder, so I can use the specified XSD for reference. Even if I could use the XSD from the target resource, somehow, this could be manageable

Comment: I think this will be the best way to do your task with a slight improvement: The downloaded schema should be treated as a generated resource (for not being part of your revision control and mvn clean to move it away). For this reason you should put it somewhere under your build directory (target) and add this as source directory in your JAXB plugin.

Comment: I have yet to find a way of referencing XSDs that exist under target package (generated classes)

Comment: If you have your own schema e.g. within directory src/main/schema and your copied one in target/schema: <xs:import ... schemaLocation="../../../target/schema/copied-schema.xsd"/>.

Comment: apparently spending too much time on a simple problem, forces you to think of more complex solutions that the simple ones. I will try it, and im pretty sure it will work. thanks!

Comment: I am accepting your answer @karsten since this is the one I used.